# Web Addin deployment: Sideload vs Admin center deployment

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

We are working on excel web add-in - for the moment it is a Ribbon element with a task-pane shown when a button on the Ribbon is pressed.

**Technical details**: we implemented shared JavaScript runtime

**Use Case**:
So we have an Excel web Add-in which is deployed through MS Admin center (we upload the manifest directly through admin center and make it available for our MS Teams users). The Add-in is correctly loaded for users when excel file is opened in the browser (sic! MS Teams has got a problem here - if excel file is opened in MS Teams the Add-in is not loaded but ok - we live with it for the moment)

At the same time the same Excel web Add-in is deployed by our developers using private deployment (sideload). The Add-in is correctly loaded when excel file is opened in the browser.

**Problem**:
There is a serious problem - with the first solution one important feature is not available - the automatic show of the task pane after F5 (refresh) is pressed in the browser.
With the second method of deployment the task pane is shown correctly after refresh (F5 in the browser).

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Please clarify what is the "first solution"? Pressing F5 in Visual Studio sideloads the add-in. This has no connection with an add-in that is deployed by centralized deployment.

Comment: Centralized deployment - F5 in the browser will reload Add-in ok but no activation of the task pane
Sideload the addin - F5 in the browser reload Add-in ok AND activates the task pane

Comment: Sorry for misleading - not Centralized deployment but a deployment through MS Admin center for Add-Ins

Comment: Sorry. But this still makes no sense. F5 is for developing an add-in in Visual Studio. It sideloads the add-in. It doesn't make any sense to speak of F5 in the context of some other way of deploying the add-in. Can you provide a link to what you call "deployment through MS Admin center for Add-ins"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: That is Centralized Deployment. It is for production add-ins. Sideloading with F5 in Visual Studio is for add-ins being developed. If your add-in is deployed with Centralized Deployment, why are you pressing F5? Why do you even have Visual Studio open?

Comment: Sorry but where in my question or answer I talk about Visual Studio??? F5 I press in the browser to reload the web excel

Comment: That wasn't clear. You mentioned sideloading and F5 so I thought you were pressing F5 in Visual Studio to sideload. Can you please rewrite the "Problem" in your question to give more context?

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin we found a problem with our way of filling the excel file. After correction it started to work fine.

For our case (Centralized Deployment without App Store) we put "EXCatalog" both for *store* and *storeType* attributes.

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Comment: yes, but it was more than this, @RickKirkham could you have a look on another problem I posted...